# A too complicated lookup

Tags: string-manipulation, algorithm

I have the following keys:

```
nm = {"bay", "ica", "rat", "tat", "dax", "dow", "sp5", "nas", "mean", "total"};
```

which I want to use to find a corresponding entry in the following vector:

```
ln = {"baywa deu", "icahn usa", "ratos swe", "tata ind", "dax", "dow","sp5", "nas", "mean", "total"};
```

I have written:

```
Sequence @@ ln[[FirstPosition[StringPosition[ln, "tat"],{{__Integer}}]]]
```

which returns the desired result:

> Sequence["tata ind"]

I feel there should be a more elegant way to perform a simple lookup like this.

Comment: depending on how you use that and how important lookup speed is for your application I think you should also consider Picketts solution: if you build the Association once then the lookup of keys in it will be the most efficient way to get at the desired data...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if the keys are unique, then this seems to be rather elegant, short and still clear:

```
Pick[ln, nm, "tat"]
```

probably look at the documentation of `Pick`...

Comment: Very nice and astonishing. Couldn't find this "StringPick" in the docu :)

Comment: @eldo: it's just a trivial special case of pattern matching, but it sometimes is good to remind that pattern matching also includes simple equality in that way :-)

Comment: @eldo: I just have had a look at the other answers and your own proposed code and am not so sure whether my code really solves your problem. When answering I understood it as if you'd want to get the element in `ln` for which `nm` equals the search string, but what you and the others have coded actually does something else (match by string similarity). Can you probably explain what "corresponding" means in your question?

Comment: I introduced your Pick to my application and it works perfectly. The keys are unique.

Comment: Aaah - just noticed that the ordering of `ln` corresponds to that of `nm`. Indeed Albert's method is best.

Comment: @eldo: My version only works if keys are unique and the length of `ln` and `nm` are equal and "corresponding" means that the nth element of `ln` corresponds to the nth elment of `nm`. This is for what the `Pick` solution works, if it is what you need then thats fine. Your code (and Taikis solution) actually wouldn't need the key list `nm` as you just select the entry which starts with the same characters as the search string which for the given example data (`ln` and `nm`) happens to be the same thing, but could be something very different for other cases...

Comment: Please accept my acceptance. For my simple case your sorrows don't apply.Your warnings are, however, gentlemanly.

Answer (score 6):

Another option:

```
AssociationThread[nm -> ln]["tat"]
```

If you store `AssociationThread[lm -> ln]` in a symbol you can use it for many quick lookups without having to recreate the association every time.

Without `Pick` and `AssociationThread` you might do something like

```
Identity @@ Cases[Transpose[{nm, ln}], {"tat", v_} :> v]
```

Note that I'm using `Identity` instead of `Sequence` to pluck off the `List` head. This displays `tata ind` instead of `Sequence["tata ind"]`.

Comment: I think that you should mention that if the OP wants to search for several keys he could do `lookup=AssociationThread[nm->ln]` and then look up a given key with `lookup[searchKey]`. That way one would avoid the relatively expensive build of the `Association` and once that has been build using it would AFAIK be the most efficient way for such lookups.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Good point, I did that.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
SelectFirst[ln, StringMatchQ[#, "tat" ~~ __] &]
```

Admittedly my method is not as elegant as others, but it's fast if your `ln` and `nm` are large:

```
ln = ConstantArray[t, 10^5] /. t :> StringJoin@RandomSample[CharacterRange["A", "z"], 10];
nm = StringTake[#, 3] & /@ ln;
```

The following

```
Timing[SelectFirst[ln, StringMatchQ[#, nm[[1]] ~~ __] &]]
```

gives

```
{0.000024, LlPKqZyoEV}
```

on my machine, whereas

```
Timing[Pick[ln, nm, nm[[1]]]]
(* Out[] = {0.002479, {LlPKqZyoEV}} *)

Timing[AssociationThread[nm -> ln][nm[[1]]]]
(* Out[] = {0.054521, LlPKqZyoEV} *)
```

Update: My method is actually slower than the `Pick` approach in later positions, but doesn't require prefabricating the keys.

Comment: I just made some comments to my solution: I now believe that my solution (by luck) might do what the OP wanted, but yours correctly does what his example code is doing. Concerning speed I think we compare apples with oranges as what my code does is actually something less difficult than what yours does...

Answer (score 1):

```
Pick[ln, Tr /@ StringPosition[nm, #], 1] &@"dow"
Pick[ln, Tr /@ StringPosition[nm, #], 1] &@{"dow", _ ~~ "at"}
```

Let's you use single and lists of targets, patterns (unlike straight pick)... assumptions about list correspondence apply, returns results in order of nm.